# EmberJS, Rail and third-party OAuth2 login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Now I'm looking for more than two days for a solution for the following problem. I have an EmberJS client-side javascript app, that uses my server-side Rail RESTful API. Authorization is done via access token.

Now I want to give the user the ability also to login with OAuth2 from Google, Twitter and so on. [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) uses [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) for third party login, but OmniAuth needs a server side session. Because I build a RESTful and stateless API, I didn't want to use a session on the server. So I decide to build it on my own with help of [Google+ Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow), but the example there also uses a session.

Does anyone have a solution for a similar problem or some hints for solving my problem?

**EDIT 1**

Because OmniAuth doesn't fit well in my setup, I started to create a own implementation for third-party OAuth2 login following [Googles help](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=de#validatinganidtoken). Everything works fine at the moment. But I didn't implement the CSRF protection explained under heading `1. Create an anti-forgery state token` on the site from Google mentioned above. My problem is, how could I store this CSRF token without using a session. Would it be enough to store it in Database and look it up in the callback request from Google later?

**EDIT 2**

I followed this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2?view=asciicast). There three possible cases, if a user want to sign-in with an extern oauth provider:

1. The user already signed-up with extern oauth, then he got a Doorkeeper access token.
2. The user has an account, but didn't sign-in with extern provider before. After oauth flow we only have to create a new authentication for this user.
3. The user didn't have an account and now tries to sign-in with extern provider. Here we have to redirect the user to the sign-up page, we also can use informations from the oauth provider to pre-fill in the sign-up form, but until the user pushes the sign-up button, we have to save the authentication.

My question now is, what is a good practice to save such informations (authentication, oauth2 csrf-token) server-side in a REST API, without using a session. I have to save these information on the server, because the user should not have the possibility to manipulate them on the client-side.

Maybe I also should create a new question for pros and cons of token and session authentication with Ember apps and possible solutions for both?

Here is my authentication controller:

```
class Api::V1::AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def oauth
    # redirect to google/twitter/...
    login_at(params[:provider])
  end

  def callback
    # callback from provider
    provider = params[:provider]
    if @user = login_from(provider)
      doorkeepter_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(:resource_owner_id => @user.id)
      @data = {
        access_token: doorkeepter_token.token,
        user: @user
      }
      render 'oauth/complete'
    else
      # user has no account, create a new one
      @user = User.new
      @user.email = @user_hash[:user_info]['email']
      @user.authentications.build(:uid => @user_hash[:uid], :provider => params[:provider])
      @user.oauth_pending!
      if @user.save
        doorkeepter_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(:resource_owner_id => @user.id)

        @data = {
          access_token: doorkeepter_token.token,
          user: @user,
          errors: @user.errors
        }
        render 'oauth/complete'
      else
        render 'oauth/error'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in the Ember.SimpleAuth repo that shows how to use Facebook as an external authentication provider: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/7-external-oauth/index.html. It basically does it the same way Discourse does it or was doing it 2-3 months ago (not sure whether they changed it) while it doesn't require a server side session.

Supporting Google would work basically the same way.

Comment: Hi, my client-side setup is the same as in the example you give above. Also the server-side callback is like this example. My problem is more, how to go on after the callback. If the user already has a authentication, then he got a token from my own API, that's not the problem. The problem is the workflow for a new user, were I must save the authentication somewhere on server until the user creates his new account without password. So I want a similar workflow like Discourse uses, but without saving the authentication for a new user in a session.

Comment: not sure what you mean - maybe you can post some code somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I updated the Facebook Auth example so that the server part is optional - it now uses the Facebook JS SDK: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/7-facebook-auth.html. Maybe that help you to get an understanding how Google Auth could be implemented - I'm sure it's going to work quite similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) project? It supports OAuth2.

Comment: Yes and I use it for my own API-Authentication together with Doorkeeper. But I want to give the user the ability to sing-in/sign-up with google/twitter OAuth and for that I need the same flow like OmniAuth, only without using a session. I edited my question to clarify my needs.